# Proper Way for Handling Observables for Async Pipe Rendering

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, async-pipe

I am trying to retrieve information from an Observable Object.
but I can't figure out how to do it properly.
such as this for example, [Dog API](https://dog.ceo/dog-api/)

it should return a JSON object

```
{
    "message": "https://images.dog.ceo/breeds/setter-english/n02100735_10064.jpg",
    "status": "success"
}
```

for such, I have a service function

```
  getRandomImage(): Observable<Random> {
    return this.client.get<Random>(`https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random`)
  }
```

however when I try to render it on HTML

```
<div>
  <p *ngIf=" random$ | async">{{ random$.message }}</p>
</div>
```

I get error message

```
Property 'message' does not exist on type 'Observable<Random>'
```

also, can someone please explain to me in simple terms what this function does

```
getListFacts(length: number, limit: number) : Observable<facts[]> {
    return this.client
        .get<{ data: facts[] }>(`https://catfact.ninja/factsmax_length=${length}&limit=${limit}`)
        .pipe(map(({ data }) => data));
}
```

Like, I tell it to return Observable of Array of Facts, with a get request that should return an object with contains an array of facts named data, then what does the pipe map do ?

Thank you

I am trying to use Observables with Async Pipe for Rending.
but I can't quite understand how to properly write observable retrieval functions for proper rendering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main problem is that you are accessing the observable `random$` directly, when in fact you want to access the object emitted by that observable. In order to achieve what you want, you can add `as randomImage` in your html-code and then access `randomImage`.

I created a working example:

First the **TS-File**:

```
random$: Observable<RandomImage>;

constructor(private client: HttpClient) {
    this.random$ = this.client.get<RandomImage>(`https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/image/random`);
}
```

Then the **HTML-Code**:

```
<p *ngIf="random$ | async as randomImage">{{ randomImage.message }}</p>
```

---

**Regarding your question about the map-operator**

The following code retrieves the data array wrapped in an object. You then use the `map` operator to extract the array from the object, so that ultimately only the array **without** the wrapper object is returned:

```
getListFacts(length: number, limit: number) : Observable<facts[]> {
    return this.client
        .get<{ data: facts[] }>(`https://catfact.ninja/factsmax_length=${length}&limit=${limit}`)
        .pipe(map(({ data }) => data));
}
```

Comment: OK, 1 more question please; 

Why in the getListFacts example, I could render the information without doing the "async as X" 

<div>
  <p *ngFor="let fact of facts$ | async">{{ fact.fact }}</p>

</div>

Comment: When you write `*ngFor="let fact of facts$ | async"` then  `facts$ | async` is executed before the loop even starts.  The `of` in `let fact of` refers to the whole term `facts$ | async` and not just to `facts$`. In your previous example you directly referred to the observable `random$`  by writing `{{ random$.message }}`. Therefore your previous example was a different case.

Comment: I suggest to put brackets around `facts$ | async` in order to make more clear what happens in your code:  `<p *ngFor="let fact of (facts$ | async)">{{ fact.fact }}</p> </div>`

Comment: sorry but I am stuck once again. 

now I am trying to use Football API [API](https://www.api-football.com/documentation-v3)

this end point for example [ENDPOINT](https://v3.football.api-sports.io/players?search=Ronaldo&team=541)

It should return a response array with player object and statistics object inside. 
I wrote this

HTML-Code 

`<div>
<p *ngIf="(player$ | async) as player">{{player.name}}</p>
</div>`

Comment: TS-Code

  `getPlayer(){
    return this.client
    .get<{response : any}>(
      `https://v3.football.api-sports.io/players?`,
      { headers: { 'x-rapidapi-key': API KEY }, params : {search :'Ronaldo', team : 541}}
    )
    .pipe(map(({ response }) => response['player']))

  }`

Comment: What I know is, I need to retrieve the response[0]['player']

Comment: OK I found the solution to my issue :)